# How to analyze Heap Dumps

Tags: memory, heap-memory, analyzer

I am successful in generating Heap Dumps of my application machine but I do not know how to analyze it. Can someone tell me how to?

Answer (score 3):

Use jhat utility for Java on Sun solaris.

A good example is here https://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/heap_dumps_are_back_with

Answer (score 1):

You can try VisialVM, for some reason my heap dump wasn't loading in jhat but was in visualVM.
It give you a graph of the class that are taking much of the heap. 
here where to get it: http://visualvm.java.net/download.html